# Find lowest or equal value on unsorted data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I am trying to find the first cell of a range containing a number lower or equal than the lookup value. The range is unsorted, and it must stay that way.

`MATCH` function was my first choice, but it is not working on un-sorted data.
For example, the below situation should return a result of 4 for the lookup value of 3 (since 2 is the first number equal or lower than 3, and it is the 4th number in the array). There is no exact match in this example, and `MATCH`with `match_type=-1`returns 3. I need to find a solution to return '4'.

```
UNSORTED_MATCH of LOOKUP_Value=3 in array:
8
6
99
2
11
17
18
5
```

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the value you are seeking in C1, this appears to return the correct row number.

For the **minimum** non-negative difference between the numbers in column A and the target lookup number, the formula would be,

```
=MATCH(C1-MIN(INDEX(C1-(A$1:A$8)+(C1-(A$1:A$8)<0)*1E+199,,)),A:A, 0)
```

For the **first** number less than or equal to the target lookup number, the formula would be,

```
=MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$9)+(A$1:A$9>C1)*1E+99, , ))
```

Comment: this one fails as well if lookup value is 7, and the array is:15
8
4
99 
2
11
17
18
5;it returns 9, but it should be 3 (because the 3rd number is the 1st number lower than the lookup value

Comment: I just noticed that the question title got edited: I am not looking for the lowest value - I am looking for **the first value** in the rage that is lower that the lookup value

Comment: Apparently I did not understand the requirement the first time around and only met expectations by coincidence. See my edit above for a second method.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to do the trick, but could you please explain a bit what the arguments of the `INDEX` function are here? I am not familiar with the `+` and the 1E+99; I get thte idea, but I don't understand the details

Comment: `1E99` is a very large number (a 1 followed by 99 zeroes). `A$1:A$9>C1` is going to be true or false. A false is zero and a true is 1. Each row number is looked at and any row where column A is greater than C1 gets 1×1E99 added to it. Any that is equal or less than gets 0×1E99 added to it. It's pretty safe to say that anything that has 1E99 added to it is not going to be the minimum of anything so you are left with the row numbers that have values in column A that are equal to or less than C1. The `MIN` of these would be the first one.